# Program won't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this exercise and the first part of the program was running fine but I must've done something because now when I try to run it will just show `None` and and nothing seems to be 'wrong'. I don't know enough to even figure out what's wrong.

```
def main():
    """Gets the job done"""

#this program returns the value according to the colour
def re_start():
    #do the work
    return read_colour

def read_names():
    """prompt user for their name and returns in a space-separaded line"""
    PROMPT_NAMES = input("Enter names: ")
    users_names = '{}'.format(PROMPT_NAMES)
    print (users_names)
    return users_names

def read_colour():
    """prompt user for a colour letter if invalid colour enter retry"""
    ALLOWED_COLOURS = ["whero",
               "kowhai",
               "kikorangi",
               "parauri",
               "kiwikiwi",
               "karaka",
               "waiporoporo",
               "pango"]
    PROMPT_COLOUR = input("Enter letter colour: ").casefold()

    if PROMPT_COLOUR in ALLOWED_COLOURS:
        return read_names()

    else:
        print("Invalid colour...")
        print(*ALLOWED_COLOURS,sep='\n')
        re_start()
main()
```

Comment: Is the displayed indentation correct? Because if so, your `main` function is just a docstring, with no body, so of course this does nothing useful. It looks like you tried to simplify, but you omitted the necessary code to understand what you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: I improved the text in the body.  Using the best English you can usually helps get you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

The only function you call is `main()`, but that has no statements in it, so your code will do nothing. To fix this, put some statements in your `main()` and rerun your code.

Comment: For example, I am guessing you would want `def main(): read_color()` .. also, I would change your second function to `def re_start(): read_color()`